# discord.py: How to use "-" in a command's name?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to create a command like that:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def add-cash(ctx):
```

Obviously that doesn't work for functions. But is there a work around or something to still use `-` in a command's name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-` is not a valid python identifier, so you cannot just create a python function to name the command.

Instead, `@bot.command` decorator has a name parameter so you can write the following code instead:

```
@bot.command(name=“add-cash”)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def add_cash(ctx):
```